# How to add addition column setting property for a Single line of textbox or any predefiend sharepoint column type

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, custom-field-types, customization

[image]

How to add additional custom properties for the column under **Additional Column Property** as shown above on pic for predefined type such as Single line text or multiple lines of text etc. so that I can programmatically generate(dynamically) the form(NewForm, EditForm & DisplayForm) by reading these values from code.

Example :-

Some additional configurations I want to append as below:

- **Availability for user**: If users choose:
- **Hidden**: This column will not be seen by non-Admin users. It can only
  be seen by Admin users.
- **Editable**: This column will be available and editable for all users.
- **Read-only**: This column will be visible but read-only for non-Admin users. It can only be editable for Admin users.
- **Information Group**: This column is belonging to the selected
  Information Group which is a master data list. For each information
  group, the system will display the configured column accordingly
  within the selected group.

Please help me to find out the way to add these additional properties to all the predefined column type.

Note :- I know how to add Custom properties for new Custom type but I need to know/is it possible to add these custom types for the existing SharePoint fields type.

Comment: This does not look like a standard SharePoint screenshot. Are you using 3rd party software?

Comment: The above one is just a design which I want to implement.

Comment: You can customize the New/EditForm with SharePoint Designer and add any HTML5 code you want

Comment: This is not about new and edit form its more about adding custom properties to the column.